# Hydro install hangs on "ldconfig deferred processing now taking place"

Tags: ros-groovy, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am an existing ROS Groovy user on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I have been trying to install ROS Hydro using

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full
```

but no matter what I do, the installation suddenly stops at the following:

```
Setting up ros-hydro-rqt-tf-tree (0.3.3-0precise-20140130-2331-+0000) ...
Setting up ros-hydro-rqt-robot-plugins (0.3.3-0precise-20140208-0437-+0000) ...
Setting up ros-hydro-stage (4.1.1-5precise-20140130-1745-+0000) ...
Setting up ros-hydro-stage-ros (1.7.2-0precise-20140201-1433-+0000) ...
Setting up ros-hydro-simulators (1.0.2-0precise-20140208-0545-+0000) ...
Setting up ros-hydro-desktop-full (1.0.2-0precise-20140208-0614-+0000) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
turtlebot@TurtleBook:~$
```

If I try to run the install again, I get:

```
ros-hydro-desktop-full is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 114 not upgraded.
```

..but I can clearly see it has **not** installed as opt/ros/hydro has no "stacks" folder.

I can repeat the process by calling apt-get remove and then apt-get autoremove, but it never completes properly. I've tried using a different internet connection and that doesn't help anything.

Does anyone know why this happens? If I need to provide more information on my setup, please do let me know.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135666/hydro-install-hangs-on-%22ldconfig-deferred-processing-now-taking-place%22/) by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on ROS Answers with karma: 504 on 2014-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the installation has completed successfully. Are there other folders in /opt/ros/hydro ? Does /opt/ros/hydro/setup.sh exist?

I think the migration to catkin has done away with the stacks folder. I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't exist any more.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) on 2014-03-05**:
You are right! I feel very silly right now.
I suppose I was expecting some sort of message that indicated the installation was finished, as well as the fact that I was so sure I'd seen reference to a stacks folder in Hydro before. Thanks!